# Add ability to exclude questions posted by "New contributors" to SO search

Tags: discussion, search, filtering

Please add ability to exclude questions posted by "New contributors" to SO search.

The reason I would like to see this implemented is overall low quality of vast majority of those questions.

Comment: Generally, feature requests need to be justified; you can't just say, "Hey, please do this", and not explain why, nor what the benefit of doing so would be.

Comment: It needs to be a part of your request, not in a comment; comments can disappear at any time, for any reason.

Comment: @DeanKuga: "*how could it possibly negatively affect your SO experience?*" It would lead to fewer bad questions getting the appropriate response (down/closevoting as needed), eventually leading to a situation where to the average person (ie: someone who isn't using this filter) the site looks like we *want* bad content. Thus creating a self-fulfilling prophecy, but one that you *personally* won't notice simply because you won't see it. Segregation doesn't work.

Comment: They're neither exempt from normal rules nor are they specially protected. And since you *very much know this*, it's clear the purpose of this question is nothing but polemics and any further engagement is futile. Unfortunately, not even the "new contributor" label would have helped to ignore it, though.

Comment: @DeanKuga: If you believe that the presence of this icon de-facto creates a "protected class" "except from normal rules"... then why don you *say that in your question* as part of your justification? You'd still be wrong, but at least you would have some basis for what you want.

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/7496/reputation-based-filter-for-search-results

Comment: @rene I tried that but it doesn't seam to work on SO. I added is:500 to my search but immediately found questions posted by users whose rep was under 500...

Comment: @DeanKuga strange: works for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20%5bwinforms%5d%20is%3a100%20is%3aq&mixed=0)

Comment: @rene try [c#] [winforms] is:50000 is:q and the fist question poster will have well below 50k...

Comment: @DeanKuga not for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgrpl.png which browser and userscript manager are you running?

Comment: @rene Interesting, I'm using Chrome currently and don't have access to FF. The help page does not have that option documented either...

Comment: I'm on chrome as well, using [Tamper Monkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) as my user script manager.

Answer (score 13):

No, let's not.  Stack Exchange is about the content, and the content *alone*.  Who posts something doesn't matter; all that does is the quality of the post itself.  By adding a filter that focuses on a user stat instead of the content, all we're doing is focusing on user aspects, which goes against the whole premise of SE.

Focus on the content.  Filter out tags you don't like, or you think are problematic.  Focusing on the user is a bandaid.  Fix the root cause, don't just plaster over it.

Comment: No, the root cause is that the *system*, ie. Stack Exchange itself, doesn't do a good job preparing new users for our expectations, and that leads to frustration and hostility when they run into curation activities.  The system needs to do a better job of setting expectations, which will alleviate that disconnect.  Won't stop everyone, but it'll lessen the amount of crud we get.

Comment: Who's BtL?  I'm not familiar with that reference.

Comment: Bill the Lizard...? But if it's true that many, many questions posed by new contributors are off-topic–does anyone not agree?–it's also true that Dean Kuga's feature request sorely lacks detail and a solid proposal despite being a member of SE for eight or more years.

Comment: Yep.  Totally missed that.  @DeanKuga No, he doesn't.  He's just stating that your proposed solution does nothing to actually solve the problem; it just pushes it onto someone else, somewhere down the line.

Comment: @fbueckert Am I not fundamental enough to be recognized by a three-letter-acronym?  ;p

Comment: @BilltheLizard Sorry, BtL, but you're not really top of mind most days. :P  You'll have to forgive me the lack of due deference.

Comment: @DeanKuga it lacks details, proof/data, and a convincing argument. I never said the question was unclear. It is very clear but because it lacks details it will not convince the team that your proposal is serious or to actually turn it into reality.

Answer (score 5):

The way I see it, the problem isn't new users *per se*, it's the "overall low quality" of certain questions (to quote the question).

Thus, I think the solution is to not look at the person, but rather the post. We already have a way to roughly gauge the quality of questions: post score. And we already have a way to only see questions with a score above *X*: by searching for [`is:q score:X..`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a1..%20is%3aq)  (replace *X* with the minimum score). You can bookmark this search in your browser to save it. Yeah

---

Also, date ranges are similarly supported in search by using [`created:X..Y`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=created%3a2010..2012).